# Is increasing the MaxRecycledViews has an effect on the Recyclerview performance?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, epoxy

I have a `Recyclerview` with multiple items, it is a details screen that has a different items type instead of implementing it with `NestedScrollview` I used `Recylcerview` inspired by [Airbnb](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/epoxy-airbnbs-view-architecture-on-android-c3e1af150394) to use Recyclerview for static content 
as they said

> to give us faster page load times as well as easy animations.

however, there is an item type that is calling `onCreateViewHolder` multiple times because there is more than 5 instance for it, 5 is the default number of `MaxRecycledViews` and as I know the `onCreateViewHolder` is inflating the view again which cause a performance issue.
I'm wondering if I increased the number of **`MaxRecycledViews`** will cause any performance issue? because increasing that number will prevent the `onCreateViewHolder` to be called each time the MaxRecycledViews exceeded 
here is an example of how my `Recyclerview` looks:

A
B
C
D
D
D
D
D
D
E
F
G
H

where the letter represents an item type.
so my solution for that is to increase the number by doing that

```
mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(D,10);
```